# Grails Getting Started: Hello World Example Getting Error 500

Tags: grails, groovy

Just started with learning Grails. I have some knowledge of Groovy, but I am mainly a Java developer.

https://docs.grails.org/5.2.5/guide/single.html#aHelloWorldExample
When following this Guide, I have created the Hello World Example project.
After creating the `hello` controller, I then run the application, and could access the web page at http://localhost:8080

Then when accessing the controller from this page, or from http://localhost:8080/hello, I then get an Error 500.

```
grails> run-app
| Running application.....
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
<=======2023-01-30 16:53:11.391 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1384)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1149)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I did not miss a single step from `Installing Grails`, and `Creating an Application`.
Maybe something with the Guide which has not been updated according to the latest version for Grails?

Comment: Works fine for me. Check the app's created directory structure for the index view at the root and the generated default view for the created controller.

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting. I am not familiar with the grails directory structure at all.
The index file here grails-app/views/index.gsp? The grails-app/views/hello/ is empty.

Comment: Should there be an hello.gps under grails-app/views/hello/?
It was not created by grails when I created the controller. The Guide does not say anything that I should create it myself either.

Comment: I think I forgot a step from the guide
>  In any text editor, edit the new controller — the HelloController.groovy file — by adding a render line.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a step from the Guide

> We now have a controller so let’s add an action to generate the "Hello World!" page. In any text editor, edit the new controller — the HelloController.groovy file — by adding a render line. The edited file’s code should look like this:

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {

    def index() {
        render "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am glad that you got it worked out.  FYI... You may be interested in our Getting Started Guide at https://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html.